# Adding two values in Prometheus

Tags: performance, kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

We need to add results of two queries in Prometheus. Snippet is below:

```
(probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{job="SSL-expiry"} - time() < 86400 * 738 )*1000 + (node_time_seconds*1000)
```

but the result says no data as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please check query is correct or not. I think query is not correct.

Comment: @SachinArote both the queries are giving results when we run separately When adding both of them gives no result. Please suggest If I am doing anything wrong

Comment: This part of query is working fine I just checked on my prometheus instance `(probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{job="SSL-expiry"} - time() < 86400 * 738 )*1000`

Comment: For this `node_time_seconds*1000` you need too add job name and then multiply this by 1000

Comment: Or else use `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{instance=~"$target"} - time()` query for same result. Here target you need to add instance name or you can add variable in grafana then select instance from variable.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an empty result if the metrics do not match. The reason is that for [binary operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) `vector1 <op> vector2`

> vector1 and vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of
>   vector1 for which there are elements in vector2 with exactly matching
>   label sets. Other elements are dropped.

You must at least add a `on()` or `ignoring()` [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) keyword specifying the labels (names) on which the (name and) value match. You may have to add grouping instruction if you have one to many matching.

Fill the `???` in the following expression such that label match:

```
(probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{job="SSL-expiry"} - time() < 86400 * 738 )*1000 + ON(???) (node_time_seconds*1000)
```